# Which button calls javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have an HTML for with 2 buttons

```
    <li>
    <!--<input type="button" onclick="getOptions()" value="Click Me!" style="margin-left:156px">-->
    <button class="submit" type="button" id="orderTickets" onclick="">Order Tickets</button>
    <button class="submit" type="button" id="startAgain" onclick="">Start Again</button>
</li>
```

Both buttons call the the external script file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
 $("#departing").datepicker();
 $("#returning").datepicker();
 $("button").click(function() 
 {
    var destinationTo = $("#myDestination option:selected").text();
    var departingFrom = $("#myDepart option:selected").text();

    var departing = $("#departing").val();
    var returning = $("#returning").val();

    var numAdults = $("#adults option:selected").text();
    var numChildren = $("#children option:selected").text();

    var travelType = $("#class option:selected").text();

    if (departing === "" && returning === "")
    {
        alert("Please enter your travel dates.");
    }
    else if (returning === "")
    {
        alert("Please enter a return date.");
    }
    else if (departing === "") 
    {
        alert("Please enter a departing date.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        confirm("Please confirm your travel: outward journey from " + departingFrom +  " on " + departing + " to " + destinationTo + " returning on " + 
        returning + " adults " + numAdults + " children " + numChildren + " travelling in " + travelType + " coach " + "?");
    }
 });
 });
```

I only want the button "orderTickets to run the script. I'm sure I can establish the buttin ID within the script then determine if I want to run it, but not sure how. The other button "startAgain" simply clears the form! Maybe my attempt is not the best solution?

HTML and javascript is not my thing and would appreciate some help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
$("#orderTickets").click(function() 
 {
.
.
.
```

instead of

```
 $("button").click(function() 
 {
.
.
.
```

A little Ps:
$("#orderTickets") selects by id attribute, if you want to select by class you can use $(".orderTickets")

Comment: I want to give a little info too :
'$("button").click(function(event) 
 {
     if(event.target.id === "orderTickets"){
.
.' 
this code assigns function to all button's click event. And you can check if the clicked button is your button by this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a submit handler on the form itself and change the `type` of `#orderTickets` to `submit` instead of `button`. A button with `type="button"` will not submit a form

This way if user uses keyboard `enter` you catch the event also and aren't relying on `click` of a button (which may never occur).

If any of the validation fails just return `false` to prevent the event completing.

```
$('#formID').submit(function(){
    var errors = false;
    /* do your validation making errors= true if anything fails */

    return !errors;    
});
```